# How to write a script for starting nodemon and mongod

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bash

I want to make a bash file that automatically runs nodemon and mongod.
I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

workingDirectory="$(pwd)/"
serverFolder="${workingDirectory}first-app/caffeineOverflow"

cd "${serverFolder}"
mongod &
export caffeine_overflow_jwtPrivateKey=ok 
nodemon &
```

I run it with sudo so that I can run mongod. I get the following error: 
exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating

What should i do in order for this code to run?

Answer (score 0):

That means that another instance of `mongodb` server is running. Which is very likely since `mongod &` runs the process in the background and may stay running if it's not properly shut down. Include a [`mongod --shutdown`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-shutdown) step in your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

workingDirectory="$(pwd)/"
serverFolder="${workingDirectory}first-app/caffeineOverflow"
cd "${serverFolder}"

# Ensure that mongod is not running by killing it
mongod --shutdown

# Continue
mongod &
export caffeine_overflow_jwtPrivateKey=ok 
nodemon &
```

Comment: I get this error:                                                                                                                throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Comment: @Giannis you also need to shut down the `node` process running in port `3000` before running `nodemon`